# Prevent php session_start() to send a cookie

Tags: php, session, header

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent PHP from sending a cookie when calling `session_start()`.

My use case is for a site optimisation:

- (1a) I first open a session/send headers.
- (1b) Then generate and output some text content.
- (1c) To enhance session read/write I call "session_write_close" as soon as I don't need to write in the session anymore.
- (2) Finally I have a post-page rendering process (for stats) that requires a write access to the session. The session is closed, I cannot call session_start() again since it sends a cookie and it's to late for that. This is a computation-heavy process, so I have to do it after the page is sent to the client.

The client already received a session-cookie. So I don't need `session_start()` to send a new (and redundant) one.

Does someone know a way to intercept the cookie or something similar ? Of course I want to avoid the "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent". This error is invisible for the user because the page is already renderered but it looks ugly in the logs.

My question seems to be a redundant one, but it is not. I know how headers and content work (send headers first, content after). It's just that PHP does not let me do what I want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a way to prevent PHP from sending a cookie when calling session_start().

Yes there is, by telling PHP to not use cookies for sessions. The PHP setting is [`session.use_cookies`](http://php.net/session.use_cookies):

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); # disable session cookies
session_start();
```

By default cookies are enabled because they are considered more safe then using URL parameters (see [*Sessions and security<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php)).

> (2) Finally I have a post-page rendering process (for stats) that requires a write access to the session. The session is closed, I cannot call session_start() again since it sends a cookie and it's to late for that. This is a computation-heavy process, so I have to do it after the page is sent to the client.

It's probably possible to tell PHP that the cookie is already set by adding it into the [`$_COOKIE` superglobal array<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php). I never experimented with it, but in case you use `session_start()` and PHP sees that the session cookie has been already set (by the browser, not PHP, `$_COOKIE` represent the browser cookies), it won't send the headers (again) to set the cookie (which as I understand you is what you want).

---

**Edit:** Some test script to play around with:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');

echo "Incomming Cookies:\n";
print_r($_COOKIE);

// to simulate that this is a new session, the session cookie is removed
// which makes PHP think it is a new session when invoking session_start()
// unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);

// run the first session
session_start(); // creates the session cookie (as we don't have one yet)
printf("Session %s has been started: %s\n", session_name(), session_id());
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['variable'] = isset($_SESSION['variable']) ? $_SESSION['variable']++ : 0;
session_commit();

printf("Session has been closed, remaining id is: %s\n", session_id());

// visual confirmation that session cookie has been created
echo "Outgoing Cookies:\n";
print_r(headers_list());

// run the second session
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); # disable session cookies
session_start();
printf("Second session %s has been started: %s\n", session_name(), session_id());
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['2nd-variable'] = isset($_SESSION['2nd-variable']) ? $_SESSION['2nd-variable']++ : 0;
session_commit();
```

You need to call it with a web-browser (and PHP sessions must be configured to work).

Comment: Great, the first solution works `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0)`.
The second solution does not seem to have any effects (I already tried it yesterday actually) but it can be relative to my php configuration. I will spend some more time later on this second solution. Thanks !

Comment: I did run some tests with `$_COOKIE`. It actually works but this would be the same as using `ini_set();` and with `ini_set()` it's more clear what it does. I'll add a script to the answer I used for playing around, some code about `$_COOKIE` is commented. Uncomment it to generate a new session id for the first session. This also shows how `$_COOKIE` is related to `session_start()`.

Comment: The `ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');` works perfectly for the cookie header, but not for the cache header that will expire the SID cookie. See the answer from @techdude to use `session_start(['use_cookies' => '0', 'cache_limiter' => '']);`

Comment: @Code4R7: That is because when I wrote the answer, that options parameter was not yet available. `session.cache_limiter` should do the trick with ini_set as well, but controlling it via `session_start` looks indeed much more practical. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @hakre I wasn't aware about the availability of the option. I think its great you had figured it out already. Today, more than five years later, I find myself in the process of handling my own cookies because set_cookie() has no option to set a 'SameSite' attribute, and I find your answer quite helpful.

Comment: @Code4R7: Have you seen http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php ?

Comment: @hakre Yes, and AFAIK there is no option to set a SameSite=strict attribute on the cookie header like OWASP suggests that we do. Which makes sense because the attribute is currently experimental and not supported in IE11. The `$secure` parameter only sets the `Secure` attribute. But be careful setting that parameter, because IE11 wil not send the cookie over HTTP unlike FF58. My homebrew cookie functions are now working, so they must be a little bit safer than the default set_cookie().

Comment: More recently, overriding the `use_cookies` setting will result in an error like `session_start(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`, essentially swapping one error for another.  Same with the `cache_limiter`

Comment: @Umbrella: I haven't checked, but probably that is that headers are already sent (like the warning says) s the change has been applied too late?

Comment: @hakre Well, yes, but... That's the point of the question, no?  To re-open the session without sending new headers, to avoid issues with headers already being sent?  Turns out this solution that used to work to prevent errors produces a new error in more recent versions of PHP.  PHP 7.3+ (and I think maybe 7.1+) doesn't care that it doesn't need to send new headers, it complains anyway now.

Comment: @Umbrella: Yes, this was more a feedback question to better understand your specific requirements. And yes, if the session already used cookies (and did send headers already) it might just not be possible to change this later on (regardless of the PHP version). So I can fully understand that this does not fulfill any requirements under any circumstances, it's more of showing one way (under specific circumstances) where it can (but must not) work. /e: maybe output buffering can be of use for your case.

Answer (score 8):

I thought I should mention another great way to prevent the cookie (and the cache limiter) headers from being sent when calling session_start.

The session_start call takes an options array where you can set any of the session. prefix variables, and you can disable these things for just that call.

```
session_start(array(
   'use_cookies' => '0',
   'cache_limiter' => ''
));
```

Note that use_cookies keeps the cookie from being sent, and setting the cache limiter to an empty string keeps it from updating the cache headers (not the best documented feature).

Here are two notices that this will fix (this is helpful when you need to work through multiple sessions).

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent
```

and

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

Comment: This should be the top answer! +1

Comment: More recently, overriding the `use_cookies` setting will result in an error like `session_start(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`, essentially swapping one error for another.  Same with the `cache_limiter`

Answer (score -3):

You can use [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) function to buffer the headers/content, you may clear the buffer contents using [ob_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

Comment: ob_start does not buffer header. Only body content. So it doe snot work.